# Intellij Idea 14 cannot find the set usage type for public static variables

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I've accidently discover that `IntellijIdea 14` does not show the `Value set/write` type of usage for `public static` variables.

```
public class Test {

    public static boolean B_VALUE;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(B_VALUE);
    }

    public void test1() {
        B_VALUE = true;
    }

    public boolean test2() {
        boolean v = B_VALUE;

        B_VALUE = !v;
        return v && ("test2".equals("TEST2".toLowerCase()));
    }
}
```

Press <kbd>Alt+F7</kbd> on `B_VALUE`, and get result:

[image: Nobody ever read image description]

You can see that we have at least 4 usages in test code (2 read and 2 set), but only read usages are lighted.

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, I just tried this and saw 4 usages, 2 for read and 2 for write.

Please make sure the *RED* icon on the left side, near the bottom, is ticked ("Show write access")